# any way to see or highlight the element pseudo states in the devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am trying to find a way to get dynamic information for a specific element what are the pseudo states applied to them. Like hover, focus, checked, active.

FYI This is not the same as triggering the pseudo state. I want to see what is happening to a specific element as we use the browser, not to trigger a state.

Preferable something I could use within devtools but even a javascript snippet would be helpful. Hope it is clear what I am trying. Let me know if not.